# Blackberry onChange event triggering issue

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

```
<label for="frmAllegation-TimeReported">Reported Time</label>
<input type="time" name="Reported Time" id="frmAllegation-TimeReported"     onchange="changeSave(this);" /><br>

<label for="frmAllegation-IncinOccDate">Date Started</label>
<input type="date" name="Reporting Date" id="frmAllegation-IncinOccDate"  onchange="changeSave(this);" /><br>

<label for="frmAllegation-IncinOccText">Date Text</label> 
<input type="text" name="Reporting Text" id="frmAllegation-IncinOccText" onchange="changeSave(this);" /><br>

function changeSave(frmInput)
{
alert("Changed");
}
```

When using **time;date;select;**  the **onchange** isn't called. Its strange because if you type in it, it's called but when blackberry native date,time or option lists pop up it prints it to the form but doesn't call `onChange`...

So basically `onChange` is called when its text, but not time,date,select...
Work arounds or solutions anyone?

Also this works fine on Chrome so I don't think its a code problem...

The only other work around I could think of is doing it `onFocusOut` but this wouldn't be my preferred option...

More info here:

[Naviagation Focus Issue](https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks/issues/120)

[^^ Offcial Developer Bug Issue](https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/TABLET-633)

[On change bug issue](https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks/issues/122)

[Forum Post On Change Issue](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/HTML5-Javascript-onChange-not-being-called/td-p/1783521)

Comment: If anyone else is interested bug tracker is here: https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks/issues/122

Comment: Can you give more info about the issue? Does it happen on a the Playbook browser or device browser? If it is on the device, which device and OS version?

Comment: Smartphone application, and look at edit post :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try mutation observers http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers